# Schannel event 36888 fatal alert 48 when connecting to wireless network from a Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, wifi

One of our users has a laptop running Windows 7 which cannot connect to our wireless network.  When the connection attempt is made we get an error in the System event log, Schannel event 36888, which says:

> The following fatal alert was generated: 48.  The internal error state is 552.

This is followed by an event claiming that the certificate could not be verified, suggesting that the fatal alert occurred while trying to verify the RADIUS server certificate.  The event includes a copy of the certificate in the event data but I don't know how to extract it in a useful form.

Other apparently similar Windows 7 laptops can connect, as can Windows 10 laptops.

We are using WPA2-Enterprise and Microsoft PEAP user authentication.  Turning off "validate server certificate" allows the connection to succeed but is not an acceptable long-term solution.  The correct certificate is selected in the certificate list, all the settings are the same as on the working laptops.

What might be wrong with this particular Windows 7 laptop and how can I fix it?  What troubleshooting steps should I be taking?